# Read the SMS activation code automatically in Xamarin Forms instead of manually typing it by user

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I wrote a project with Xamarin Forms. When every user has signed up, I send him/her an activation Code to confirm it and the user has to insert it to enter the app. But I am looking for a plugin or a way that the user does not need to insert the activation Code.

I want the activation Code to be read automatically without the need to enter it manually.

Comment: you can't do this in iOS - it does not allow you to read SMS messages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First add the required permissions in AndroidManifest:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Here is SmsReceiver class in Android project:

```cs
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Telephony;
    using Java.Lang;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    namespace MyProject.Android
    {
        [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "SMS Receiver")]
        [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED", Intent.CategoryDefault })]
        public class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            private const string IntentAction = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
            private static readonly string Sender = "SMS Sender number here";
            private static readonly string[] OtpMessageBodyKeywordSet = {"Keyword1", "Keyword2"}; //You must define your own Keywords
            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (intent.Action != IntentAction) return;
                    var bundle = intent.Extras;
                    if (bundle == null) return;
                    var pdus = bundle.Get("pdus");
                    // var castedPdus = JNIEnv.GetArray(pdus.Handle);
                    var castedPdus = JNIEnv.GetArray<Object>(pdus.Handle);
                    var msgs = new SmsMessage[castedPdus.Length];
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    string sender = null;
                    for (var i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var bytes = new byte[JNIEnv.GetArrayLength(castedPdus[i].Handle)];
                        JNIEnv.CopyArray(castedPdus[i].Handle, bytes);
                        string format = bundle.GetString("format");
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu(bytes, format);
                        if (sender == null)
                            sender = msgs[i].OriginatingAddress;
                        sb.Append(string.Format("SMS From: {0}{1}Body: {2}{1}", msgs[i].OriginatingAddress,
                            System.Environment.NewLine, msgs[i].MessageBody));
                        //Toast.MakeText(context, sb.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                        //Log.Error("Vahid", sb.ToString());
    
                        var msgBody = msgs[i].MessageBody;
                        if(!sender.Contains(Sender)) return;
                        bool foundKeyword = OtpMessageBodyKeywordSet.Any(k => msgBody.Contains(k));
    
                        if (!foundKeyword) return;
                        var code = ExtractNumber(msgBody);
                        MessagingCenter.Send<RegisterSecondPageModel, string>(new RegisterSecondPageModel(), "OtpReceived", code);
    
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    //Toast.MakeText(context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            }

            private static string ExtractNumber(string text)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return "";
                var regPattern = @"\d+";
                var number = Regex.Match(text, regPattern).Value;
                return number;
            }

        }
    }
```

**Note:** In order to filter out the coming SMSes  and detect only our own SMS we can apply these two filters:

1- Ignoring all SMSes that their sender numbers are not our SMS sender number.

2- Sometimes our SMS sender might send different SMSes to our clients, for example one SMS to send an activation code, and another to inform and confirm user's successfully registration in system. That said, we gotta distinguish them. For that we can search message body in order to find some pre-defined keywords. Of course our SMS server has to stick to a defined body format. "Activation", "Code", "Activation code" could be some example keywords in English language. Of course keywords should be defined in each language accordingly.

Here is RegisterSecondPageModel inside PCL project:

```cs
public class RegisterSecondPageModel
{
    public RegisterSecondPageModel()
    {
        SubscribeToOtpReceiving();
    }
    
    private void SubscribeToOtpReceiving()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<RegisterSecondPageModel, string>(this, "OtpReceived", (sender, code) =>
        {
            ActivationCode = code;
        });
    }
}
```

Another note is that as Jason already said, iOS doesn't allow apps to read SMSes.

Comment: hi,thanks a lot ,Can you send an example ,Because When I wrote your code in to a new project  I have some Error Like this:

Comment: hi,thanks a lot ,Can you send an example ,Because When I wrote your code in to a new project  I have some Error Like this:1-The name 'Util' does not exist in the current context  2-'object' does not contain a definition for 'Handle' and no extension method 'Handle' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: I'm gonna update the answer to address your problems.

Comment: BTW, always bear it in your mind that many times answers are meant to give us merely the adequate idea in order to solve our problems. Having said that, you have to adopt and change the codes to to your own version. For example you can replace "RegisterSecondPageModel" for your own pageModel, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. I'll reply you in the email.

Comment: Hi,Please check Your mail,Thanks

Comment: As I tested it with Persian characters it works as expected. Are you sure that's not from other codes of your project?

Comment: When I use  Persian character in Keyword  I Received error.

Comment: nothing happens in my code. nothing. is there a dependency i should use?

Comment: @waletoye Please be more specific. Which part is not working? BroadcastReceiver or your Entry being filled?

Comment: @VahidShir Both, in a simulator i send sms the phone receives it, but not the app. not the BroadcastReceiver, not the entry.

Comment: Make sure you set up BroadcastReceiver correctly including inserting permissions in AndroidManifesr.xml. And then place a breakpoint in OnReceive() method to see if it is hit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already sure about your clients having a SIM card in their device, then you can create a token and authenticate backwards, sending an SMS containing your token to from clients' device to your number.

Pros:

- No blocked numbers: Sending messages from client is not blocked even if you're on their blacklist or they're blocking advertisements and unknown senders.
- No costs on your side for authentication.
- This works also in iOS which you can't read but can send messages.

Cons:

- Client may be using another number in another device. This can be overcome by creating easy-to-type tokens which expire fast enough not to attract brute force attacks.
- Client may not be able to send an SMS to your number due to several reasons including but not limited to not having enough account charge.