# How to instantiate a BroadcastReceiver on just one page of my PCL project?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am developing a xamarin cross platform application. 
I need to get an activation code by SMS automatically on my login confirmation page. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48608061/11282839) works if I intanciate SmsReceiver in my MainActivity, but how can I instantiate the SmsReceiver class only on my login confirmation page? 
SMS activation will only be used once on one page, I do not want it to be active for the lifetime of my app. It would be a waste. 
I want my app to read incoming messages only when the login confirmation page is active. How can I do this?

Comment: this would only work on Android.  iOS won't allow you to read SMS messages

Comment: No problem, better work on just one than on none. For IOS I intend to use this => (https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2018/10/28/using-ios-12-otp-security-code-autofill-in-xamarin-forms/).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your `BroadcastReceiver` from being always "listening" you just need to mark it as `Enabled=false` in the declaration, this will prevent the BrodcastReceiver from being statically-registered in the Manifest.xml.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = false, Label = "SMS Receiver")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED", Intent.CategoryDefault })]
public class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    // Code omitted for simplicity
    ....
}
```

Later on the **Activity** you want to be listening you will need to call

`RegisterReceiver()`

Passing the instance of the `BroadcastReceiver` and the `IntentFilter`.

something like:

```
[Activity(Label = "MainActivity", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity: Activity 
{
    private SmsReceiver _smsReceiver;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _smsReceiver = new SmsReceiver()
    }

    protected override OnResume() 
    {
        base.OnResume();
        RegisterReceiver(_smsReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
    }

    protected override OnPause() 
    {
        UnregisterReceiver(_smsReceiver);
        base.OnPause();
    }
}
```

As you can see I am also unregistering when I don't need/want to be listening anymore.

This is done with the method:

`UnregisterReceiver();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks @pinedax. But how do I access the Activity that I want to hear if in the Android project I only have the MainActivity to start the App and everything else is created by my PCL project?