# How can we create custom entry to fill the OTP automatically. like this in xamarin form cross paltfrom

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[image]

the entry box accepts only 1 character .ui design should be like this

Comment: Refer this link. This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607897/read-the-sms-activation-code-automatically-in-xamarin-forms-instead-of-manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a simple example to achieve what you want with Xamarin.forms:

In Xaml:

```
<StackLayout Padding="0,100,0,0">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">

                <Label x:Name="label1" Text="" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="30"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">

                <Label x:Name="label2" Text="" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="30"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Column="2">

                <Label x:Name="label3" Text="" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" HeightRequest="30"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Column="3">

                <Label x:Name="label4" Text="" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3" HeightRequest="30"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>

        </Grid>

        <Editor TextChanged="Editor_TextChanged" Keyboard="Numeric" TextColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0"/>

    </Grid>

</StackLayout>
```

And in code behiend:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    List<Label> labels;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        labels = new List<Label>();
        labels.Add(label1);
        labels.Add(label2);
        labels.Add(label3);
        labels.Add(label4);
    }

    private void Editor_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var oldText = e.OldTextValue;
        var newText = e.NewTextValue;

        Editor editor = sender as Editor;


        string editorStr = editor.Text;
        //if string.length lager than max length
        if (editorStr.Length > 4)
        {
            editor.Text = editorStr.Substring(0,4);
        }

        //dismiss keyboard
        if (editorStr.Length >= 4)
        {
            editor.Unfocus();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < labels.Count; i++)
        {
            Label lb = labels[i];

            if (i < editorStr.Length)
            {
                lb.Text = editorStr.Substring(i, 1);
            }
            else {
                lb.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I created `custom renderer` both in iOS and Android to hide the cursor. For more detail, you can check my sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/OTP-Entry). Feel free to ask me any question!

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.

Add the following NuGet package:
[Xamarin Forms Pin View](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FormsPinView/)

```
 // iOS:
 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
 {
     ...
     global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
     PinItemViewRenderer.Init();
 }

 // Android:

 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
 {
     ...
     global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
     PinItemViewRenderer.Init();
 }
```

Add PinView to your page:

```
  ...
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormsPinView.Core;assembly=FormsPinView.Core"
 ...
     <local:PinView
         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
         TargetPinLength="4"
         Validator="{Binding ValidatorFunc}"
         Success="Handle_Success" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this NuGet package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/OTPEntryControl/1.0.6

Implementation:
namespace: xmlns:otpcontrol="clr-namespace:OTPControl;assembly=OTPControl"

```
<otpcontrol:CustomOtpControl x:Name="otpControlName"  OtpLength="5" FillBorderColor="Orange"   HorizontalOptions="Center"  />  
<Button Text="Get Otp"  Command="{Binding GetOtpCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference otpControlName},Path=SelectedOtp}" />
```